# Adding a formatted string to a Word Document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to create a Word file, add and format a lot of text from an Excel file to it using VBA.

At the moment I use the following code for this (only the important parts are shown here):

```
With appWD
  .Visible = True
  .Activate
  .Documents.Add
  .Selection.Font.Size = 12
  .Selection.Font.Bold = True
  .Selection.TypeText "Name, "
  .Selection.Font.Size = 10
  .Selection.Font.Bold = False
  .Selection.TypeText "First Name"
End With
```

In reality my code generates a Word document with much more different text elements and styles used. As each step of the code changes something in Word the macro is really slow and takes 2 hours or more to execute.

That's why I'm searching for a way to generate a Word object where I store a text, then add all they font styles and so on and at the end I add it to the word document before I start with the next text snipped. I hope this way is much faster because of less interactions between Excel VBA and Word Application.

Is there such a way and how can I do it? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance,
M. Born

Comment: We need more information to really make any comments on your process. For example, your process could be slow because you're directly accessing an Excel `Range` instead of using a [memory-based array](https://www.thesmallman.com/arrays-with-excel-ranges). There could also be such a large amount of text in the Word file and your formatting logic may be redundant. Please expand on your problem description and provide more of an example and/or more code.

Comment: Hello Peter, I have 3 sheets in Excel with several thousands of lines where I get the text information from. Using a For-Next-Loop I go through them and put the strings together which I then add to the Word file. 
As I'm writing Excel VBA macros for many years I know how to optimize the code there but Word VBA is quite new for me so I'm not sure if and how I can improve the code there.

Comment: From the code that you have posted it seems that you have a lot of standard text in addition to the text from the workbook. Your starting point should be a Word template (.dotx / .dotm) that contains all the standard text and style definitions. If the template is constructed correctly, using styles *not* directly applied formatting, it should be possible to restrict the code merely to transferring the data.

Comment: I don't see why you would bother generating a Word file with styles using VBA. Instead, start with a document formatted with styles using the program interface, then place your data into it. Also, use the Range object instead of Selection, it's much faster.

Comment: @Timothy and John: I don't use paragraph styles, only styles for single or a group of words. As you can see in my example both strings belong to the same paragraph. Both strings are be created by the macro using values from the Excel file. 
I usually create a string, then set the format like bold, size and so on, and finally put the string to the Word file.
If I use the Range object, can I format it before I add it to Word?

Comment: My advice to you still stands. You should be starting with a Word template that already has the required paragraph and character styles set-up. With only a few exceptions Word's `Range` object has the same formatting properties as `Selection`.

Comment: Can I use the Range object to format a string with all styles I need and then add the object in a single step to Word? I still don't understand the meaning of this object but I'll try to find something like a tutorial for it.

Comment: *"Can I use the Range object to format a string with all styles I need and then add the object in a single step to Word?"* - No

Comment: The `Range` object is like `Selection` in that it represents a location in the document. Unlike `Selection`, it does not move the cursor/insertion point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll try it once I understand the syntax and the meaning of collapsed and not collapsed ranges.